# My sound is distorted in Doom3. How can I fix it?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, games

I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. I've read the Doom 3 guide here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Doom3

and installed Doom 3 successfully. It runs but the sound is horrible (very static-y). The terminal output is filled with these repeating lines:

```
snd_pcm_writei 4096 frames failed: Broken pipe
preparing audio device for output
snd_pcm_writei 4096 frames failed: Broken pipe
preparing audio device for output
```

I've tried using the following:

```
doom3 +set s_driver oss +set s_numberOfSpeakers 2
```

but when I do there is no sound at all. This was in the terminal output:

```
    ------ OSS Sound Initialization ------
    WARNING: failed to open sound device '/dev/dsp': No such file or directory
    WARNING: sound subsystem disabled
```

Can anyone explain what the 'snd_pcm_writei 4096 frames failed: Broken pipe' error means and how to fix it so the sound plays normally?

Comment: Here are some advices. Check it. http://zerowing.idsoftware.com/linux/doom/#head-8c36163f1dfc3a253ef72c0f821b0b0dd2fc17b1

Comment: Maybe you should kill pulseaudio server and run a game with oss driver. Someone at Ubuntu Forums says it helped http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1568010

Comment: Yup. Already read the idsoftware.com page - that's where I got the idea to use the '+set s_driver oss'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run a game with the following commmand.

```
pasuspender ./doom3.x86
```

Or try these:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-oss

quake3 +set s_driver oss +set s_numberOfSpeakers 2

aoss quake4
```

Comment: Two questions - what does pasuspender do? Second - I thought I had alsa already installed (when I ran another program under Wine I noticed it was using an alsa driver for sound and that program's sound worked fine.) If I don't have it installed and I install it like you suggested will it overwrite/remove the default Ubuntu 11.10 audio?

Comment: pasuspender disables PulseAudio for an app. As I remember it wouldn't affect your existing installation, it just add oss drivers for alsa. Anyway, you can always purge this package.